# Problems between Adapter and Array in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, adapter

My adapter does not seem to take my Array as  a parameter ..

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

List<Character> characters;

public MyAdapter(List<Character> list) {
    this.characters = list;
}



@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return characters.size();
}

@Override

    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int itemType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_cell,viewGroup,false);
        return new MyViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Character character = characters.get(position);
    holder.display(character);
}

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private final TextView name;
    private final TextView secondname;
    private final TextView numero;


    public MyViewHolder(final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        name = ((TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name));
        secondname = ((TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.secondname));
        numero = ((TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.numero));

        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

            }
        });
    }

    public void display(Character character) {

        name.setText(character.getNom());
        secondname.setText(character.getPrenom());
        numero.setText(character.getNumero());

    }
}
```

}

and my MainActivity :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

List<Character> characters = new ArrayList<>();
private RecyclerView recyclerView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    ajouterVilles();

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    recyclerView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter());


}


private void ajouterVilles() {
    characters.add(new Character("Romain", "Leroy", 0625421535));

}
```

}

and this is the log :

```
Error:(28, 33) error: constructor MyAdapter in class MyAdapter cannot be applied to given types;
    required: List<Character>
    found: no arguments
    reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

I tried to pass List in argument but without success.

Someone can help me?

edit: my 1st problem is solved but now , i have a Fatal Exeption :

FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Process: ad.training.repertoire, PID: 24006 android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x656235d

at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:340)

at android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getText(ResourcesWrapper.java:52)

at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4171)

at ad.training.repertoire.MyAdapter$MyViewHolder.display(MyAdapter.java:69)

at ad.training.repertoire.MyAdapter.onBindViewHolder(MyAdapter.java:40)

at ad.training.repertoire.MyAdapter.onBindViewHolder(MyAdapter.java:15)

Comment: You expect it to magically know you want the list to be passed to the adapter? You have to do that yourself `recyclerView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(characters));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your Main Activity like

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

List<Character> characters = new ArrayList<>();
private RecyclerView recyclerView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    ajouterVilles();

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    recyclerView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(characters));


}


private void ajouterVilles() {
    characters.add(new Character("Romain", "Leroy", 0625421535));

}
}
```

Because in adapter your adapter constructor is like

```
public MyAdapter(List<Character> list) {
    this.characters = list;
}
```

Comment: This solved my problem but now i have an fatal exeption :

Comment: @Xof..if my solution is solved your problem then please accept my answer

Comment: @Xof and tell me in comment or edit your question about your fatal exception

Comment: I tried to pass List in argument but without success.

Someone can help me?

edit: my 1st problem is solved but now , i have a Fatal Exeption (edited in the post)

Comment: @Xof..your fatal exception saying Resources$NotFoundException means you have to debug the code to check specially the following code...private void ajouterVilles() {
    characters.add(new Character("Romain", "Leroy", 0625421535));

}

Comment: Thanks for your answer, its work with String.valueOf(getNumero())

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the Adapter a list argument,

```
MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(characters);

recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```